# WPF: Apply the same ItemTemplate to multiple comboboxes

Tags: xaml, datatemplate, itemtemplate

In my application, I created a DataTemplate for a ComboBox.  (See the XAML below.)  I want to apply this style to multiple ComboBoxes in the application.  How can I do this?

```
<ComboBox Name="mouseColorCmbx" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="SimulationOptionsPanel_mouseColorCmbx" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0 0 0 0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="Forms:ColorInfo">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,3,0,0">
                        <Border Margin="2,0,2,0" BorderThickness="1">
                            <Border.BorderBrush>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="Black"/>
                            </Border.BorderBrush>
                            <Border.Background>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=Color}"/>
                            </Border.Background>
                            <Rectangle Height="10" Width="25"/>
                        </Border>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
```

Comment: I tried adding the DataTemplate to the Resources of this user control.  (I named it template1.)  Then I tried to set the ItemTemplate property of the comboboxes to template1.

Comment: I actually made a silly mistake.  I tried to reference the Name property on my style instead of the Key property.  My style was not applied to my control because it could not be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [application resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746624.aspx).
Adding your own style(template) to global resource allow you share it with multiple controls.

Comment: I accepted your answer.  However, I discovered that my problem had nothing to do with this.  I was actually using the Name property on a shared resource when I should have used the Key property.  That was why  my style could not be found.